# CSS - how to prevent this table from overflowing?

Tags: css

I have designed a webpage to retrieve stock information from Yahoo Finance, using Javascript. I now have issues to format the table, as the table contains too many columns to display on screen.

What I would like to achieve is to let the user scroll the table to see the columns / rows beyond predefined limits.

I tried to combine the use of these formats, to no avail:

```
#stockDataTable {
    max-width:600px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Would you have any suggestions to format the table?

I have saved the html and css code in jsfiddle.net:
http://jsfiddle.net/lcazarre/PCW6F/

Thanks,
LC

Answer (score 3):

You can't prevent a table from growing in width, but you could simple insert into a DIV with a fixed width and `overflow: scroll` on the DIV.

Comment: Do you know, that you should accept an answer, if it is the corret solution for your problem?

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap-table">
    <table id="stockDataTable">
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap-table {
    overflow:scroll;

    /* Add some padding so the scrollbar isn't overlapping the table */
    padding-bottom:10px; 
}
```